# How to i can integrate LUIS bot with multiple QnA maker

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Can someone please provide the solution for integrate LUIS with multiple QnA KB.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Sorry but your post tone is a bit rude and untimely. Please provide us with example of what you tried and which error do you encountered. Reade [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting next time. Thanks for your attention, have a nice day

Comment: Does the answer below fit your question?

Answer (score 1):

You would basically create a LUIS app, then for each intent have it call the appropriate QnA KB. Tutorial on how to do this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis), "Integrate QnA Maker and LUIS to distribute your knowledge base".